# Why is this icon being clipped?

Tags: flutter

[image]

As you can see, the face icon on the right is being clipped and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
new Container(
  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(style.wideMargin, style.wideMargin * 2,
      style.wideMargin, style.wideMargin),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
  child: new Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      new Expanded(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            new PrecisionTextOverflow(
                'Name of a thing',
                lineWidth: style.longLineWrappingWidth,
                mainTextStyle: style.blackParagraphText),
            // Because PrecisionTextOverflow paints itself directly, the UI
            // doesn't know its size so we use a blank Text object to make the
            // column center itself correctly.
            new Text(' '),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      new Transform(
        transform:
            new Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -style.defaultMargin, 0.0),
        child: new IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          icon: new Icon(Icons.face,
              size: style.headingText.fontSize,
              color: style.favoriteColor[isItemFavorite]),
          onPressed: favoritePressed,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

That PrecisionTextOverflow is a class I made of a StatelessWidget that uses a CustomPainter to paint text on the screen. I don't imagine it's related to the issue at hand, but just FYI.

I've tried removing the padding from the outer container but it doesn't help. I've tried adjusting the transformation to shift the icon to the left but it just shifts it in its clipped form. What am I doing wrong? How can I correct this?

**Edit:**
Okay, I did a render tree dump and it looks like the enclosing Row sets its height as 24.0, which passes on down to the IconButton which gives itself a size of (24.0, 24.0). Is there a way to increase the height of a Row? Or should I rethink my whole structure?

Comment: I would start by dumping the render tree ("t" if you're using `flutter run`, or else call `debugDumpRenderTree()` from `package:flutter/rendering.dart`). That might give you an idea of who is doing the clipping.

Comment: The row is probably sizing itself based on the IconButton (size is set after the children are laid out). If you upload the render tree dump somewhere we can look at it and see if it says anything useful.

Comment: Here's a link to a txt file with the render tree dump. Google Docs doesn't display the line characters correctly so if you open it in a regular text editor it displays correctly: https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/file/d/0B-6EzwxsJ2BKWVh1SE5qV0ozWTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That log has a lot of IconButtons in it. Which one is the one with the problem?

Comment: The page only has one IconButton on it so I'm not sure what that's about, but it should be the first one you come to in the tree. It's a child of a Tranform.

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. I'll post an answer. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the `size` on the Icon, rather than the `IconButton`. If you move the `size` argument to `IconButton` it should work.

What's going on is that the `IconButton` is defaulting to 24.0, and since you have it in an unbounded space it's being size-limited to 24.0 via a `LimitedBox`. It then tries to pass that size down to the `Icon` via an `IconTheme` inherited widget, but the `Icon` has been told to ignore that and be size 30.0 regardless.

I'll improve the docs.

Comment: The docs were terrible. I've gone and improved them based on this conversation. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a different reason

Wrapping the `IconButton` in a `Container` with a fixed `height` and `width` can cause it to clip like in the example.